# reactJS doubts and questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Hello guys I would like to use reactJS but it's not clear for me why do I have to use it, I already use Jquery and it works fine for me, I can use Java script and manipulate all the DOM the issue here is why? Why should i use it and what kind of things I can do with reactJS that I could not make with Jquery.

I hope you can give a hand or simple examples because I'm very confused thank you.

Comment: if jquery works just fine for you then some simple advice would be to keep using it. i however, like react because it simplifies *state management*. the idea behind react is that you re-render your whole application (efficiently) *any time there is a change to your application state*. This is different from jquery where you'd attach an event listener manually then manipulate the DOM inside a call back. You could easily forget to add a callback or forget to update a piece of the DOM. The result of using react is a consistent UI without much work, especially when you're using redux etc.

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest advantages is the component system for writing code. You can build all your html in blocks and then just import those blocks where you need them. You can also modify how those blocks are loaded using the component lifecycle for added control and optimisation.

These methods really help structure how you perceive information flow throughout your site.